# Changing the default LAUNCHER activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, manifest

I want to have a splash screen before the main activity comes in but my "main activity" was automatically set as a launcher one. I searched a lot on stack overflow posts and on google but i couldn't find a solution for my case. Below i am posting my manifest.xml file and yes i know it's pretty messed up(i tried some stuff).

UPDATE: I updated my manifest.xml file below according to the suggestions in the comments and after trying to solve the following issue that came during testing the app with another developer:

*The app gets launched, the splash screen's background image loads in and then the app crashes and closes(sometimes even the whole AVD/Phone)*

Here are the two errors i am getting (!The FunFactsActivity.DEAD one just keeps on occurring no matter what I try).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:name=".FunFactsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FunFactsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
ERROR #1:

11-10 11:42:12.718 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:42:12.729 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 359MB/363MB, paused 538us total 10.161ms
11-10 11:42:12.729 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 354MB allocation
11-10 11:42:12.729 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:42:12.736 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 359MB/363MB, paused 555us total 7.286ms
11-10 11:42:12.736 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 372109512 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 24MB until OOM"
11-10 11:42:12.737 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
11-10 11:42:12.744 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-10 11:42:12.747 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.spdesigns.funfacts, PID: 16295
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spdesigns.funfacts/com.spdesigns.funfacts.SplashScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                            at com.spdesigns.funfacts.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:17)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 372109512 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 24MB until OOM
                                                                            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
                                                                            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
                                                                            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
                                                                            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                                                                            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4175)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
11-10 11:42:12.747 16295-16295/com.spdesigns.funfacts E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:207)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
                                                                                ... 25 more

ERROR #2(DEAD):

11-10 11:43:09.417 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-10 11:43:09.418 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-10 11:43:09.561 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.spdesigns.funfacts-2/lib/x86
11-10 11:43:09.583 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-10 11:43:09.692 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-10 11:43:11.042 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.042 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.046 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.052 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 99(8KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 359MB/363MB, paused 552us total 5.888ms
11-10 11:43:11.052 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.060 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 38(1840B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 359MB/363MB, paused 550us total 8.156ms
11-10 11:43:11.060 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 354MB allocation
11-10 11:43:11.060 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.070 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 359MB/363MB, paused 678us total 9.530ms
11-10 11:43:11.070 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 372109512 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 24MB until OOM"
11-10 11:43:11.070 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.071 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.076 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.083 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(144B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 359MB/363MB, paused 713us total 7.322ms
11-10 11:43:11.083 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.091 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 359MB/363MB, paused 546us total 7.309ms
11-10 11:43:11.091 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 354MB allocation
11-10 11:43:11.091 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 11:43:11.100 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1% free, 359MB/363MB, paused 744us total 8.983ms
11-10 11:43:11.100 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 372109512 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 24MB until OOM"
11-10 11:43:11.100 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
11-10 11:43:11.104 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-10 11:43:11.105 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.spdesigns.funfacts, PID: 16410
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spdesigns.funfacts/com.spdesigns.funfacts.SplashScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                            at com.spdesigns.funfacts.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:17)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 372109512 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 24MB until OOM
                                                                            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
                                                                            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
                                                                            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
                                                                            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                                                                            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4175)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
11-10 11:43:11.105 16410-16410/com.spdesigns.funfacts E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:207)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
                                                                                ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  `intent-filter` tag as follows and I think it will work

```
 <activity android:name=".FunFactsActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: Sadly that does not work. For some reason my app keeps on crashing with this setup.Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is in your SplashScreenActivity class.Did you put your splash screen code inside a thread and added Thread.sleep() to hold it for some second? @SteliosPapamichael

Comment: paste your splash screen class here

Comment: paste your SplashScreenActivity.java class here

Comment: package com.spdesigns.funfacts;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    }
}

Comment: It seems your code is ok. Try this 1.Run the project in another device or virtual device or uninstall the project from your device and clear the cache 2.Disable instance run in android studio

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove `<intent-filter ...> ..... </intent-filter>` 
Then your AndroidManifest.xml is look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.spdesigns.funfacts">

<application
    android:name=".FunFactsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".FunFactsActivity">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Make this changes in your Manifest file if you want to start the
>   splash screen first

```
<application
    android:name=".FunFactsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".FunFactsActivity">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: like i mentioned above this does not work either, my app just crashes!

Comment: please check my edited post to use         android:largeHeap="true"
 or decrease the size of the image you are using in splash screen.
Out of memory error is because of that

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest.xml file only launcher activity should have tag like below

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And all other activities should look like below..

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityOne/>
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityTwo"/>
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityN"/>
```

Now suppose if you want to make ActivityOne as launcher activity later then just exchange ActivityOne and  SplashScreenActivity with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample project with the following AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.spdesigns.funfacts">

  <application
      android:name=".FunFactsApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".FunFactsActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.FunFactsActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.FunFactsActivity" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

      <!-- This is needed if you want to launch the splash screen without knowing the default main -->
      <!-- you can call it with:                                                                   -->
      <!-- Intent intent = new Intent("com.spdesigns.funfacts.LaunchSplash")                       -->
      <!-- context.startActivity(intent);                                                          -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.spdesigns.funfacts.LaunchSplash"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

And the Splash screen is working as the launcher activity. So, probably you have the problem somewhere else in your code.

You can check the sample project at https://github.com/isnotmenow/funfactssample

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

1. Copy your splash image under drawable folder.
2. Create background.xml under your drawable folder. Use below code. Create `<layer-list>` item. Under layer list add below code.

```
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash"
            android:gravity="center"></bitmap>
    </item>
```

3.Edit your style.xml. Under your style add below style tag.

```
`<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    </style>`
```

4.Create one SplashActivity.java which extends to AppCompatActivity. Modify your onCreate method as below.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

5.Create one activity called ClockTimer which will extend to Application. Modify onCreate as below.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    }
```

6.Finally you need to modify your androidmanifest file. Do below changes in android manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vishal.golevr.splashscreenapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".ClockTime">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Your output will look like below[image].

Comment: this just crashes my phone :(

Comment: May I know the error? Did you followed all the steps mentioned above?

Comment: yeah i followed them exactly but i was getting an error that background.xml and background.png were duplicates(somehow) so i re-created the xml and named it background_handler.xml. But now, if i try and run the app my phone restarts.

Comment: Please try to delete other background.xml files. If you are renaming/recreating it then please add that name in style.xml also. Use step number 3

Comment: i did but it keeps on crashing when i try and run the app.

Comment: Will you do one favor, can you please add  your code so I can get idea whats going wrong.. Also please mention the error you are getting right now

Comment: Should i add all the files? like Splash activity, ClockActivity, their xmls and styles etc. ? Btw, i don't get any errors it just crashes without logging any errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158576/discussion-between-androidonhigh-and-stelios-papamichael).

Answer (score 0):

> Make this changes in your Manifest file if you want to start the
>   splash screen first

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true" // for large memory use 
    android:name=".FunFactsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".FunFactsActivity">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

> You have two option

1. To decrease the size of the image you are using ,compress the image size to 500kB or less . or

2.Add this in your Manifest file then, because according to your error you are using a large size image, and android is not able to not read that so your app is crashing out of memory error.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: the large heap solution does not work since i get another error saying that it could not allocate that much space. Maybe it would be better if i compressed it but do i need something like photoshop to do that?

Comment: You can use online compressor there are multiple site that do so eg compressjpeg.com/
 or if you are on windows you can use window picture manager , let me know if the error still occurs.

Comment: ok, so I compressed it down to 400kb but I still get the same OutOfMemory exception and I cannot figure out the issue...is it the resolution? do I need to change something to the bitmap?